# JOINING 2 rows from a table created in the query

Tags: mysql

I have one table with a list of items. There are 2 variations of each item, but they are in this main table as a single item. What I would like to do is a cartesian product of the results with the two variations.

```
SELECT * FROM items
```

will give me

```
ID
1
2
```

I want :

```
ID   Variation
1    a
1    b
2    a
2    b
```

this has to be done in the query because there is another left join that goes to that.

I can get the first variation by doing:

```
SELECT * FROM items JOIN (SELECT 'a' as Variation) as v
```

but that only gives me 2 of the 4 rows i need.

I know that if I had an actual table of variations with two rows, that would work. Is it possible to create two rows? I also tried this but it failed:

```
SELECT * FROM items JOIN (SELECT ('a','b') as Variation) as v
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want each row of items paired with either `a`or`b`you could do this:

```
SELECT * FROM items
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 'a' Variation
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'b' Variation
    ) Variations
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5dcba/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
SELECT * FROM items CROSS JOIN items AS v
```

As @Strawberry commented there's also another option:

```
SELECT * FROM items JOIN items AS v
```

Comment: Sorry, I clarified it by using 'a' and 'b' as the variants. I am not joining the same table in the second column. I want 2 of each row, where joining the table to itself would square the number of rows. 5 items becomes 25 permutations instead of 10. When i do '(select "a") as v' it's creating a table in memory that's one row. I need one with two rows. I'd rather not create an actual second table.